# Numeric pagination custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination, wp-reset-query

i create a custom page to display loop of cpt with custom field.

I need to add a numberic pagination and i try with this code but not work.

**Functions.php**

```
function pagination_bar() {
    global $wp_query;

    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
        ));
    }
}
```

**custompage.php**

```
<!--Loop Salmi-->
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'salmi',
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'paged'          => $paged )
);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <!--Colonne Contenuto -->
    <div class="salmicpt">
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container td-pb-span8">
            <div class="titlecpt"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container td-pb-span4">
            <?php if( get_field('audio_salmi') ): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_field('audio_salmi'); ?>" ><img src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cuffia-cpt-e1481533293805.png" alt="Ascolta" title="Ascolta" /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( get_field('salmi_pdf') ): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_field('salmi_pdf'); ?>" ><img src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/freccia-32.png" alt="Scarica il PDf" title="Scarica il PDF" /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div style='clear:both'></div><hr class="style-one" />
    </div>
    <nav class="pagination">
        <?php pagination_bar(); ?>
    </nav>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Where is wrong?? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're referencing the **`global $wp_query`** object in your function which you've reset using **`wp_reset_query()`**.

You can resolve the pagination by passing your custom **`$loop`** WP_Query object to the function. I also changed **`wp_reset_query`** to **`wp_reset_postdata`**

Also you're making the call to your pagination function in the **while loop** instead of after it.

**Your function should be updated to:**

```
function pagination_bar( $custom_query ) {

    $total_pages = $custom_query->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
        ));
    }
}
```

and in your **custompage.php** file:

```
<!--Loop Salmi-->
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'salmi',
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'paged'          => $paged )
);
if ( $loop->have_posts() ):
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <!--Colonne Contenuto -->
    <div class="salmicpt">
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container td-pb-span8">
            <div class="titlecpt"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container td-pb-span4">
            <?php if( get_field('audio_salmi') ): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_field('audio_salmi'); ?>" ><img src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cuffia-cpt-e1481533293805.png" alt="Ascolta" title="Ascolta" /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( get_field('salmi_pdf') ): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_field('salmi_pdf'); ?>" ><img src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/freccia-32.png" alt="Scarica il PDf" title="Scarica il PDF" /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div style='clear:both'></div><hr class="style-one" />
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <nav class="pagination">
        <?php pagination_bar( $loop ); ?>
    </nav>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks much but the problem remain..i see pagination but if i click not go on second page but reload and remain on same page. 

Link on number page are http://mysite.it/page/2/page/2/page/2/page/3?page_id=415/page/3

Answer (score 0):

**copy and pest in your function file**

```
function pagination_bar( $query_wp ) 
{
    $pages = $query_wp->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    if ($pages > 1)
    {
        $page_current = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => $page_current,
            'total' => $pages,
        ));
    }
}
```

**copy and pest code in your custompage.php file **

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array('post_type'=>'salmi','posts_per_page' => 15,'paged' => $paged);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>    
    <!--Colonne Contenuto -->
    <div class="salmicpt">
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container td-pb-span8">
            <div class="titlecpt"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container td-pb-span4">
            <?php if( get_field('audio_salmi') ): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_field('audio_salmi'); ?>" >
                    <img src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cuffia-cpt-e1481533293805.png" alt="Ascolta" title="Ascolta" />
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( get_field('salmi_pdf') ): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_field('salmi_pdf'); ?>" >
                    <img src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/freccia-32.png" alt="Scarica il PDf" title="Scarica il PDF" />
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div style='clear:both'></div><hr class="style-one" />
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <nav class="pagination">
        <?php pagination_bar( $the_query ); ?>
    </nav>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: You should explain what this code does and how it solves the problem. At the moment it's just a code dump. Not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Make following changes in custompage.php file**

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;
$args = array('post_type'=>'salmi','posts_per_page' => 15,'paged' => $paged);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>    
    <!--Colonne Contenuto -->
    <div class="salmicpt">
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container td-pb-span8">
            <div class="titlecpt"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container td-pb-span4">
            <?php if( get_field('audio_salmi') ): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_field('audio_salmi'); ?>" >
                    <img src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/cuffia-cpt-e1481533293805.png" alt="Ascolta" title="Ascolta" />
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( get_field('salmi_pdf') ): ?>
                <a href="<?php the_field('salmi_pdf'); ?>" >
                    <img src="mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/freccia-32.png" alt="Scarica il PDf" title="Scarica il PDF" />
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div style='clear:both'></div><hr class="style-one" />
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <nav class="pagination">
        <?php pagination_bar( $the_query ); ?>
    </nav>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
</div>
```

**And in functions.php**

```
function pagination_bar( $query_wp ) 
{
$pages = $query_wp->max_num_pages;
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
if ($pages > 1)
{
    $page_current = max(1, get_query_var('page'));
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => $page_current,
        'total' => $pages,
    ));
}
}
```

**This works perfectly**

Comment: It's useful to add a small description of what changed and why. It greatly improves the value of your answers to people who may have the problem from the original question.