# Wordpress multiple loops with default pagination

Tags: loop, pagination, multi-taxonomy-query

I'm trying to list advertisers in 3 categories (custom taxonomy "ad_category") as basic, casual and premium. As default query one page contains 10 results but it should be in order to display premium advertisers at top then casual and basic advertisers at last.

Ex: If I'm having a total of 30 premium and casual ads, the basic ads starts from page 4.

My Codes are:

**loop-suppliers-basic.php**

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$title = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'suppliers',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ad_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('basic_advertiser'),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'supplier_categories',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $title->slug,
        ),
    ),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

////////// Loop goes here /////////

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

**taxonomy-supplier_categories.php**

```
<?php get_template_part('loop-suppliers-premium'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('loop-suppliers-casual'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('loop-suppliers-basic'); ?>
<?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
```

**Pagination function**

`function wp_pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ));
}`

This does display in order I want but the pagination goes wrong. 
Tried using methods like **rewind_posts();*but didn't work.

Comment: what is 'wrong'? what code are you using for the pagination?

Comment: Hi Michael, it's the default pagination I'm using. I'll add the pagination code to the question as well. What happens is if I have 2 premium ads, 2 casual ads and 10 basic ads it all displays in the first page. Instead it should display the 2 premium ads at top 2 casual ads next and first 6 basic ads then paged to No:2

Comment: what is your default `posts_per_page` value? you have 3 separate queries, you will have a number of results up to 3 times whatever `posts_per_page` is. also note that you can't randomize order this way with pagination, you will get a random selection on each page with no relationship to the random selection on all the other pages, meaning you will have repeats.

Comment: Hi Milo, default `posts_per_page` value is 10. Yes, I get your point. Ignore the `orderby`. Is there any method to achieve this without having 3 separate queries in 3 files?

Comment: Did you try adding `posts_per_page` to the `$args` parameter of each of the 3 separate queries? E.g. if you want 6 posts/ads displayed per page, you'd add `'posts_per_page' => 6` to the `$args`

Comment: Hi @Sally CJ. Yes, I tried but didn't output what I expect. I hope there will be a method to have 3 different argument parameters in one loop file. Still working on it.

Comment: I think the problem is with the pagination function. It uses the global `$wp_query` object, which is why the function ignores or doesn't use the `max_num_pages` property of the custom `$the_query` object used in your loop templates. There are several options you can choose from to fix that, but can you share the code for the other loop templates, as well as *pagination.php*? I can probably help you create that one loop file, you know.

Answer (score 0):

> try now this code

```
    <?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$title = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'suppliers',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ad_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('basic_advertiser'),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'supplier_categories',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $title->slug,
        ),
    ),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

////////// Loop goes here /////////

<?php endwhile; ?>

<nav class="pagination">
        <?php pagination_bar( $the_query ); ?>
</nav>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();

endif;



function wp_pagination($wp_query)
{
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ));
}
```

Comment: and chack this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250861/resolve-numeric-pagination-custom-post-type