# Numeric Pagination on custom post page

Tags: pagination

I have a custom post page like this:

```
    <?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array("post_type" => "post", "post_type" => "viaggi", "orderby" => "date", "order" => "DESC", "paged" => $paged, "posts_per_page" => 12);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'gallery');
    $url = $thumb['0'];
    ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 ricette-box">
    <?php do_action( 'estore_before_post_content' ); ?>

    <div class="entry-thumbnail">
        <?php if ( get_theme_mod('estore_postmeta', '') == '' && get_theme_mod( 'estore_postmeta_date', '') == '' ) { ?>

        <?php }
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'estore-featured-image' ); ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        if ( is_single() ) {
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        } else {
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        }
    ?>

    <div class="entry-content-text-wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="entry-content-wrapper">
        <span class="posted-on"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></a></span>
            <?php estore_entry_meta(); ?>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <div class="entry-btn">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>" class="btn"><?php esc_html_e( 'Read more', 'estore' ); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'estore_after_post_content' ); ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->

<?php } ?>
<div class="clear" style="height:20px;"></div>

<?php

wp_reset_postdata();


?>
```

I want to add numeric pagination. How to add?

Comment: Please see this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250861/numeric-pagination-custom-post-type

Comment: thanks this solved.